# How to ReadLine and retain the carriage returns and line feeds?

Tags: c#, readline

When reading a line on a stream (for me it's actually a stream on a COM port), the returned string contains no \n or \r characters (or \r\n combinations).  For logging purposes, I would like to retain them.  At present my loop looks like this:

```
 while (newPort.BytesToRead > 0)
 {
     received = ReadLine(newPort);

     response.Add(received);
 }
```

So basically I'm reading a string and then adding it to a list of strings called `response`. What I want is for the returned string `received` to contain the \r or \n or \r\n that was in the original stream, as well as terminating a line of text.

Is this trivially possible?  Or even non-trivially!

I'm guessing this is quite hard to do.  I mean thinking about it, if I receive a \r, I have to get the next character to see if it's a \n.  If there isn't a next character I'll timeout with an exception. If there is a next character and it isn't a \n, I have to make it the current character on the next iteration, and so on...!

Comment: Why don't you just manually add a newline at the end of the string with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the OP's solution from the question post:

> Ok, I had a crack at it.  Here is what I think is right... :

```
            {
                int s = 0, e = 0;

                for (; e < line.Length; e++)
                {
                    if (line[e] == '\n')
                    {
                        // \n always terminates a line.

                        lines.Add(line.Substring(s, (e - s) + 1));

                        s = e + 1;
                    }
                    if (line[e] == '\r' && (e < line.Length - 1))
                    {
                        // \r only terminates a line if it isn't followed by \n.

                        if (line[e + 1] != '\n')
                        {
                            lines.Add(line.Substring(s, (e - s) + 1));

                            s = e + 1;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Check for trailing characters not terminated by anything.

                if (s < e)
                {
                    lines.Add(line.Substring(s, (e - s)));
                }
            }
```

Comment: I'll delete my post if the OP decides to post the answer themselves :)

Answer (score 2):

You could append `Environment.NewLine` after adding `received`.

**Update** If you need to keep the original whitespace verbatim, then there's no point using `ReadLine`. You could use `ReadBlock` in that case to read smaller chunks of a file, or `ReadToEnd` to just get the whole thing. If you need to mark new lines for processing the message, you can search through the raw string to normalize or tokenize or whatever it is you'd like to do.

Comment: I want to know if I received a single \n, a single \r or the \r\n combination.  It's important to know exactly which characters the COM port is sending me, for logging purposes.

Comment: Yes HBC, I realised this just a moment ago and have written a function to do it with ReadChar.  Still got to test it but I guess there's no trivial way of doing it.

Answer (score -2):

```
while (newPort.BytesToRead > 0)
 {
     received = ReadLine(newPort);

     response.Add(string.Format("{0}{1}", received, System.Environment.Newline);
 }
```